# I am trying to make !update command, which sends everything that you said after !update/!u

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make `!update` command, which sends everything that you said after `!update`/`!u` except I don't want it to send the `!update` or `!u`.

Code what I've tried:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'update',
    aliases: ['up', 'u'],
    description: "Update message!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1); 
        message.channel.send(message) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your args is working correctly:

```js
message.channel.send(args.join(" "));
```